# GLib-CRITICAL console-kit-daemon

Tags: 14.04, ssh, glib, console-kit

A fresh install of 14.04 with KDE installed yields the following error:

```
[...]
Jan  8 13:58:19 linuxtest4 console-kit-daemon[1969]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 20 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jan  8 14:41:34 linuxtest4 console-kit-daemon[1969]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 39 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jan  8 14:43:18 linuxtest4 console-kit-daemon[1969]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 13 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jan  8 14:43:18 linuxtest4 console-kit-daemon[1969]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 13 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jan  8 14:43:20 linuxtest4 console-kit-daemon[1969]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 61 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jan  8 14:43:36 linuxtest4 console-kit-daemon[1969]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 54 was not found when attempting to remove it
[...]
```

which tends to spam to stdout/stderr and syslog, which is rather annoying. It seems to trigger whenever I connect to the box via ssh. Any pointers on how to fix the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have been wondering about this myself but don't know what to do.

Comment: I see a LOT of these messages in the syslog... OS: Xubuntu 14.04.5 with kernel 3.19.0-78-generic. Both answers below didn't help to get rid of them

Answer (score 5):

I "fixed" it by:

```
apt-get remove consolekit
```

consolekit is no longer actively maintained.
As far as I'm aware there is a fork named *consolekit2* and apparently
for systemd users basically the same functionality is included in *systemd-logind*. As I'm only using a vm without desktop, no replacement is needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
sudo apt-get install lxpolkit
```

fixed the problem.

I am running Lubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

What caused this problem for me was that the package `policykit` was not installed, so I installed it :

```
sudo apt-get install policykit
```

The problem seems to be solved after doing this.

Comment: I have policykit installed and still get this error.

Comment: Does not work for me either.